# Input protection on a DC jack

Tags: ac, dc, protection, over-voltage-protection

I am designing an battery powered instrument with around 20-40Ah 3S li-ion batteries in it along with a 10A 3S(12.6v) external charger.

Due to ease of availability and the current capacity I have used an IEC 60320 connector to charge the battery.

[image]

My problem is that the same connector is a standard connector used for AC power usually for PC's and other electronics. I don't want someone to plug in a power cord directly in here because it is directly connected to the battery.

I have looked into over voltage protection using crowbar circuit but it seems it blows the fuse every time,

[image]

so is there any smarter way of doing this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't use the wrong connector.  As for the crowbar, blowing the fuse is exactly what it is designed to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using that connector for anything other than mains input is violating some standard or another...

Comment: Standardized connectors are only as good as the designers agreeing to follow the standard. The more we re-purpose them, the less functional the standard becomes. *cough Apple cough*

Comment: Thanks for your input, seems like I need to go for a DC barrel connector but I suppose the problem still persists as there could be several power supplies with different voltages using the DC barrel jack. (Unless I chose a not so standard connector )

Comment: But with the barrel jack, you could bring the DC into a switching regulator set for whatever output voltage you wanted.   What current do you need to charge the batteries?

Comment: Enlarging on comment of @ChrisStratton : the circuit is called a "crowbar" because it's the equivalent of putting a heavy metal bar as short-circuit across the line, as a desperate move to shut a device by blowing the fuse, or even burning out wiring. Nikola Tesla is reputed to have used an actual crowbar to shut an earthquake oscillator when unable to get to a switch.

Comment: you can get male versions of that same plug, which will stop someone from sending AC into it, unless they have a hacked cable. they used to use the connectors on the back of PC AT (not ATX) power supplies to provide AC to the monitor with one cord going to the wall.

Comment: @ChrisFernandez which standard connector has Apple re-purposed?

Comment: @nekomatic I was thinking of Apple repurposing the standard USB Type-C connector into their proprietary Thunderbolt 3 interface

Comment: @ChrisFernandez OK, I had the impression Thunderbolt 3 was an Intel standard - it's available on plenty of PC's. I'd also argue it's an extension of the connector's functionality not a repurposing - I don't know if this is required by the standard but there are no devices with Thunderbolt 3 host connectors that don't also support USB, are there?

Comment: @ChrisFernandez ok, just because I happened to come across this: Thunderbolt 3 is an [Alternate Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode) within the USB Type-C connector standard - other alternate modes include DisplayPort and HDMI.

Answer (score 1):

It's a really bad idea to use a standard connector type for a non-standard purpose, especially if the consequence of connecting a standard cable (i.e. AC mains) to your nonstandard equipment could be hazardous.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector) has a good overview of connectors typically used for DC power. As the article notes, 'barrel jack' connectors are usually only rated for a few amps, although they are seen on laptop power supplies at higher currents.

Out of the choices in the Wikipedia article I would suggest you use a **4-pin XLR connector** (chassis plug and line socket), wiring pins 1+2 negative and 3+4 positive as it describes. These are not too expensive if you look around, are rated for your required current and you would be using them in line with an existing standard.